# Sliding effect page dynamically

Tags: android

First of all, I search on forum title about sliding page and I am not using fragment view. I have one xml layout and one java document.
Xml includes one textview and one imageview also one prev and one next button.

In java file, I have and array and it includes letters: a,b,c...

My problem is that when I clicked next button, my textview and imageview will changed with sliding animation. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? Also why don't you want to use `Fragments`? If you'd use `Fragments` you could use the `ViewPager` without much further "ado". See the documenation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: whoops, meant to make an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I have lots of data in my array, and in each data I can't create a new xml file, I want to do it in one layout. Is it possible?

Comment: Guess you can create it programmatically and inject them into your layout using a layout inflater.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer to: [How to animate a slide in notification view that pushes the content view down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098083/how-to-animate-a-slide-in-notification-view-that-pushes-the-content-view-down/19098369#19098369) can be of help.

It slides a View nicely into the screen while pushing the other layout down.

Think same process could be applied to what you want.