# How to slide in slide out a view from Top to it's original position

Tags: java, android, animation, slide, objectanimator

I have a view in my activity at some position from the top. Now i want to slide it out/in to/from the Top on a button click.

Initially it should be invisible.

1) When button click it should be visible but animating from top to it's position.
2) When button click it should be invisible from it's position to top.

Can anyone have code for implementing this idea. What kind of animation is needed to write.
Please share your experience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide

Comment: sounds pretty much exactly as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098083/how-to-animate-a-slide-in-notification-view-that-pushes-the-content-view-down/19098369#19098369 I have provided an answer and working example for it